# In python 2.7, How can I compare specific items within a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

for example, I have a for loop that will append 10 random numbers in a list. I want to know how many times the next appended item is within +- 0.1 of each and EVERY previous items(not just  the previous consecutive item).

Is there a way to compare the next appended item with the rest of the items in the list?

Thanks guys.,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (Taking +- 1 as max distance):

```
import random

target = []
for x in (random.randint (1, 10) for _ in range (10) ):
    count = len ( [42 for y in target if abs (x - y) <= 1] )
    print ('{} has {} neighbors.'.format (x, count) )
    target.append (x)

print (target)
```

Using floats and max distance .1:

```
import random

target = []
for x in (random.random () for _ in range (10) ):
    count = len ( [42 for y in target if abs (x - y) <= .1] )
    print ('{} has {} neighbors.'.format (x, count) )
    target.append (x)
```

Comment: sorry for being a burden but I'm still a beginner in this. What does the 42 mean in line 5.

Comment: 42 is the meaning of life, the universe and everything. But here it is just a place holder. You can replace it with anything you like better. 43, None, or 'bigkahoonaburger' maybe.